# Unable to delete old objects in GWT

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I am using GWT for my client side part.And this is observed that internally GWT is not removing the older objects.My code snippets is something like this,

```
    ArrayList<object> var = new ArrayList<object>();

    public void example()
    {
    var.clear();
    var.add(new Myclass());
    }

    public createAndReplaceOldData()
    {
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    example();
    }
```

In above code Myclass is a GWT widget.Every time I try to reload the table with updated data.

Here after completion of createAndReplaceOldData() method I am expecting only one object to be stored in var ArrayList.Unfortunately GWT is holding all the older objects as well.Total 10 objects present after this method execution.My question is,

how to destory all the old 9 objects.

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: Your code explicitly adds 10 objects to the list, why would you expect only one?

Comment: I have modified the code snippets,please check once now.